# A-frame trigger function when two objects touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js, aframe, webvr

I am wondering how I can achieve something in A-frame where when two objects touch, a function called myFunction() is triggered with a one second delay. This means that if the objects are continuously touching, there will be a 1 second delay before the next function is triggered. How can this be done?  Simple example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
      <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
      <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
      <a-sky color="#ECECEC"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would ideally like to trigger a function each 1 second called myFunction that the sphere and square are touching. How can this be done?

Comment: I recommend sharing code with your attempt with https://glitch.com/~aframe I will be much easier to help you.

Comment: I have already shared the code, I dont see what different if would make if I shared a glitch project. If it helps, here is a fiddle of the code snippet in my question: https://jsfiddle.net/AidanYoung/m7dfornq/

Answer (score 1):

You may try setting a class on each object you want to monitor:

```
<a-box class="collidable" position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
<a-sphere class="collidable" position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
```

Then attach collision event handlers with a 1 second delay event handler in each:

```
function collisionHandler (event) {
  console.log('Entity collided with', event.detail.collidingEntity);
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('one second later...', event.detail.collidingEntity);
  }, 1000)
}

const collidables = document.querySelectorAll('.collidable');
console.log(`collidables ${collidables.length}`);
collidables.forEach(cld => {
    cld.addEventListener('physicscollided', collisionHandler);
})
```

See example here, but you'll have to figure out how to move the objects:
https://jsfiddle.net/mq9xwraf/4/

One problem is that you're going to receive events from either object on each collision (it takes two to tango, as they say). You would need to decide how to resolve that duplication of events.

Comment: I tested the code and in the fiddle and repositioned the objects to be touching and I'm not receiving the message in the console.  All I see when I open the console is "collidables 2". Even when the objects are touching, the console remains empty.

Comment: You would only receive the event at the moment that a collision was detected - if they are overlapping from the start there will be no move to trigger a bounds check, possibly. Can you make them movable (or script movement) to trigger a collision state change at runtime?

Comment: to handle duplication, use throttling. Here some more info on some of that: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/debouncing-and-throttling-in-javascript